# discord.js send scheduled message to users with role

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, discord, discord.js

I'm doing a little guide student app but for now I'm using discord as an holder for the app

What I'm trying to accomplish is not send scheduled messages since I use node.schedule for that, I'm trying to send scheduled private messages to each user that has a specific role

```
    const botconfig = require('./botconfig.json');
const token = '*';
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var classA = '?';
var sumaryA = '?';
var profA = '?';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);



  var class8_30 = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 8, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 1}, function(){
    classA = 'English'; 
    client.users.get("500087456046120961").send("Class now");
  });

});

client.on('message', msg => {

  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('pong');
  }

  if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!myclassis')){
    var args = msg.content.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    console.log(args);
    if(args[1] === '10a'){
      var t10A = msg.guild.roles.find('name', 'Class_10A');
      msg.member.addRole(t10A.id);
      msg.channel.send('You\'re now part of class 10A');
    }
  }

  if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "class"){
    let c10A = msg.guild.roles.find("name", "Class_10A");
    if (msg.member.roles.has(c10A.id)) 
        msg.author.send(aulaA);
  }

});

client.login(token);
```

The way that I have right now is messaging by id which is really neither practical nor 'automatic' 
I've watch a ton of videos, I've read the docs but I can't really find it but I'm sure it exists I just don't know how to do it and can't find how to do it

If anyone could help me I would love the help and thank the time spent on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you can solve it by first fetching the guild where the roles are applied. Then you get the role where you need the users from. Then you get all the Guildmembers and send a message to each member.

Below you can find an example of how it might work. Try it for yourself and let me know if you have any issues.

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  var class8_30 = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 8, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 1}, function(){
    let guild = client.guilds.find((guild) => guild.id === '<Guild ID here>');

    if (!guild) {
      // Guild can't be found
      return;
    }

    let role = guild.roles.find((role) => role.name === '<Role name here>');

    if (!role) {
      // Role can't be found
      return;
    }

    role.members.forEach((member) => {
      member.send('Class now!')
        // Should there be an error, log it to the console
        .catch(console.error);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello, yes It indeed worked, the message was sent but it still gave me an error but it was just that I tried DMing the bot because the bot had the role as well. Thank you for your time :)